# Remove duplicate value for particular key and add other keys value Python

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I have an array like

```
[{'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58660bc587418325258b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568'},
 {'activityCount': 1, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58650ad5874183df748b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57dccedc87418359718b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 1, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'}]
```

I want to remove duplicate value of `oId` and add other value of `activityCount` and  `jobCount` to single value.
Like this

```
 {'activityCount': 1, 'jobCount': 11, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 2, 'jobCount': 10, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 7, 'jobCount': 4, 'oId': u'57dccedc87418359718b4567'}]
```

Add others keys value related to all duplicate value and store in one field.

Edit: I know how to remove duplicate but I don't know how to add other values related to this

Comment: activityCount and jobCount is the sum of the duplicate entires values is it?

Comment: Yes @KeerthanaPrabhakaran

Comment: Can you explain how you add those values, because firstly you have zeros, and then it becomes some other values?

Comment: It is count of records in my db related to `oId`. Now I want only one value which have some of all other `acticitycount and jobcount.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this!

- for each input, check if your id is already present in your new list
- if not present append it
- else sum the required columns!

That is,

```
d=[{'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58660bc587418325258b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568'},
 {'activityCount': 1, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58650ad5874183df748b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57dccedc87418359718b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 1, 'jobCount': 1, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 1, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 13, 'jobCount': 11, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'}]
final=[]
uniq=[]
for each in d:
    if each['oId'] not in uniq:
        uniq.append(each['oId'])
        final.append(each)
    else:
        for data in final:
            if data['oId']==each['oId']:
                data['activityCount']+=each['activityCount']
                data['jobCount']+=each['jobCount']
                break
print final
```

Output:

```
[{'activityCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567', 'jobCount': 0}, {'activityCount': 14, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567', 'jobCount': 13}, {'activityCount': 0, 'oId': u'58660bc587418325258b4567', 'jobCount': 0}, {'activityCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568', 'jobCount': 0}, {'activityCount': 1, 'oId': u'58650ad5874183df748b4567', 'jobCount': 0}, {'activityCount': 0, 'oId': u'57dccedc87418359718b4567', 'jobCount': 0}]
```

Comment: Thnkx for your responce. It work well. I stuck in loops and it not able to break it.

Comment: I would choose any other solution here besides this one. It's hard to understand and unreasonably non-optimal.

Comment: Time complexity wise, the above solution(0.000999927520752seconds) is much much better than the other solution(Oersted 0.00600004196167, yeniv 0.000999927520752(same as mine)  Rahul KP 0.00100016593933) posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list and covert it to a dictionary where `oId` serves as the key and can store the cumulative numbers something like:

```
tmp = {}

for row in d:
    if row['oId'] in tmp.keys():
        tmp[row['oId']]['activityCount'] += row['activityCount']
        tmp[row['oId']]['jobCount'] += row['jobCount']
    else:
        tmp[row['oId']] = {'activityCount': row['activityCount'], 'jobCount': row['jobCount']}
```

You can probably work with this dictionary as well. Or if required convert it back to a list.

Comment: It doesnt seem to give  the right output! The sum value seems to be wrong!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran, probably because I took the list name as `data`. instead of `d`. Otherwise works well.

Comment: Yeah I understand logic. Thnkx for explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
from collections import Counter

activityCount = Counter()
jobCount = Counter()
for record in array:
    activityCount[record['oId']] += record['activityCount']
    jobCount[record['oId']] += record['jobCount']

new_array = []
for key in activityCount.keys():
    ac = activityCount[key]
    jc = jobCount[key]
    new_array.append({
        'oId': key,
        'activityCount': ac,
        'jobCount': jc,
    })
```

Comment: As I understand this will add all values of array. I want only related to duplicate values.

Comment: It will sum the values that have the same oId (the duplicates).

Comment: But in first for loop u are adding all activitycount and jobcount. ?

Comment: Not all, as I said, I'm keeping a count per oId. If you are not familiar with Counter, it's very much like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `list comprehension` + `groupby`,

```
from itertools import groupby
result = [{'activityCount':sum([i['activityCount'] for i in grp]),\
          'jobCount':sum([i['jobCount'] for i in grp]),'oId':name}\
          for name,grp in groupby(sorted(d,key = lambda x:x['oId']),\
          key = lambda x:x['oId'])]
```

Result

```
[{'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'55a646a1874183dc018b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'5783a71a874183e3158b4568'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57dccedc87418359718b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'57e229cc8741833c738b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 1, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58650ad5874183df748b4567'},
 {'activityCount': 0, 'jobCount': 0, 'oId': u'58660bc587418325258b4567'}]
```

Comment: There is a restriction here, groupby only looks for the adjacent duplicates!

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran Thankz fixed,

Comment: Well I have no idea about `groupby`. Thnkx for your respond